# How to open a folder with a "/" in its name in Outlook, using the command line?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, cmd.exe, exchange

Is it possible to open a folder with a "/" in its name in Outlook, using the command line?

For instance a folder with the name "Test A/B Folder".

This does NOT work:

```
outlook.exe /select "outlook:\\username@domain.com\All Folders\T\Test\Test A/B folder" /recycle
```

This DOES work (because there isn't a "/" character):

```
outlook.exe /select "outlook:\\username@domain.com\All Folders\T\Test\Test AB folder" /recycle
```

Comment: try escaping the `/` with a `^` like this: `A^/B`

Comment: No luck.  I've tried various escape characters, including: '^/' and '//'

Comment: it's looking like this is just a limitation of `cmd` - I would probably recommend just not using a forward- or backslash in your folder names (for the same reason nowhere else in Windows lets you).

Answer (score -1):

The command switch /select foldername starts Outlook and opens the specified folder in a new window. For example, to open Outlook 2013 and display the default calendar use:

"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2013\Outlook 2013" /select outlook:calendar